# Is Volley only available for Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, visual-studio-code, android-volley, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to write a Java code that makes HTTP requests **that would run on both Windows and Android**.

I'm given to understand that for Windows, Apache's [HTTPComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) is used, and for Android [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley) is used. But it appears neither work on the other platform.

Is there a library that works on both? Or a uniform API layer on one of them that based on the OS decides what to use?

I'm using *VS Code* for Windows and *Android Studio* for Android, both latest versions, if it is relevant.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Retrofit. According to the [official website](https://square.github.io/retrofit), Retrofit is a type-safe HTTP client for Java and Android which was developed by [Square](https://squareup.com). With Retrofit, all you need to do is declare a Java interface to represent your API. Then, you can pass the API configuration to Retrofit, and you will get back a Java class implementation of your interface.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Ktor client
but it requires Kotlin language

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can give a shot to **Swagger Editor**. It generates client code for languages, not for platforms. You need to prepare a yaml file then click **"generate client" -> "java"**. After then, you need to implement downloaded client into your project as gradle project.

code generator: https://editor.swagger.io/

documentation: https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-editor/